# How to show website work samples that are internal-only?

Tags: resume, work-experience

I work as a contractor building and modifying websites for various companies. I would like to get a regular job, and of course most employers want work samples. Most of my very best work is on applications that are internal to those companies, for employee-use only. They're behind logins, on intranets, and have closed registrations.

How can I show those as work samples? Screenshots? Videos with test accounts? A Git repo? I can't imagine any HR employee would clone my repo just to judge my work sample.

Comment: Relevant: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35716/can-i-use-anything-developed-at-my-current-employer-in-my-portfolio

Comment: Construct a portfolio of your work in your own time

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, not all of my work, but the work I'm most proud of and that best represents my current skills.

Comment: One method I used to show portfolio work was to get a screenshot of the site and remove all relevant information from it. I replaced all copyrighted or sensitive imagery with a stock image and all text with lorem ipsum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is list your projects with a description. It will be something like a custom portfolio. You can e.g. list:

> 1. Project name
> 2. Short description of project
> 3. Project domain, i.e School Management System, E-Commerce, Payroll system
> 4. Top 5 features of the project
> 5. What platform/technologies you used to build the project, e.g. ASP.Net, PHP

This will give an idea of what you have done, with what technologies you have worked, your expertise etc.

You can also add the phone number/company name/contact person for the company that you built the project for, which will add more trust for your portfolio. Make sure you have talked with that person and you have permission to add their details in your portfolio.

Comment: It helps if you can provide specific metrics on these projects as well, it will give a scope on how widely used they are as well as give credibility to your resume.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you're sharing work that isn't public, your employer might have policies forbidding sharing anything.  You asked *how*, not *whether*, so this answer assumes you have the permission.

You can [list the details of your projects](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/59760/325), as suggested in another answer, but that tells only part of the picture.  That tells an employer that you've used such-and-such technologies to do such-and-such tasks, but it doesn't show whether *you're any good at it*.  A portfolio is a *supplement* to a resume where you *show*, not *tell*.

What you put in that portfolio will depend on the nature of the work:

- If you developed the visual design of a site you can use screenshots.
- If you did interaction design, use either videos or UI mock-ups showing flows.  I would go ahead and include Balsamiq mock-ups (or whatever your tool of choice is) here, but assume that many people won't be able to use them.  This is a "for those who can" enhancement.
- If you wrote code or did back-end work like optimizing a database schema, that's harder to show.  If it doesn't violate the policies (or NDA) of the company for whom you did the work you can show code samples, same as for people applying for programming jobs, but you're going to be more limited here.
- In addition to the above, *always* include an explanation of *why* you did what you did.  What were the important design requirements?  What processes were you trying to optimize?  What platforms did this have to support?  Who were your users?

Comment: If you are screen shotting internal only websites I would check the legality of that.  Actually most of your advise could land this person in court in the right context.

Comment: @blankip to show *anything* the OP already needs to clear that hurdle.  The question made it clear that he's asking about techniques not legalities, but I'll add a note about that.